# Moving Javascript object from one array to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I want to move an object from one array to another by using the splice and push methods. Here's my code:

```
console.log(tl.tour.length);
tl.tour.push(shuttleList.splice(ui.draggable.data('keyIndex'), 1)[0]);
console.log(tl.tour.length);
```

However, if I call that code, the element is getting removed from the shuttleList array, but the tl.tour array stays empty. Both debug log calls print 0.

I should say that shuttleList is a knockout observable, tour is not.

Comment: post a working sample which shows what is tl, shuttlelist ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example

```js
var a = [1, 3, 5];
var b = [2, 4, 6];

console.log(a, b);
b.push(a.splice(1, 1)[0]);
console.log(a, b);
```

You could provide the code or try to find what was spliced.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I was resetting the tl.tour array in another part of my code.